# How did Hunter save Richard's life three times crossing Knightsbridge?

Tags: neverwhere

In Neil Gaiman's *Neverwhere*, Hunter appears at the audition and answers Door's question "Can you stop people from killing me?" (`p.124`):

> Hunter inclined her head toward Richard. "I saved *his* life three times today, crossing the bridge, coming to the market."

Is this a riddle that I'm missing? How did Hunter save Richard's life three times?

Comment: I believe we are to assume that Hunter is referring to dangers she dealt with that Richard was never even aware of.

Comment: I know it escaped me for sure. I also think I'm missing something because she is a legendary fighter, so definitely demands a hefty sum to retain her services. But she saved Richard not once but 3 times already. She protected him for free? or out of the goodness of her heart. Yet she didn't protect Anaesthesia which would mean Richard is more important for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richard had his eyes closed for much of the journey.

> “Darkness is happening,” said the leather woman, very quietly. “Night
> is happening. All the nightmares that have come out when the sun goes
> down, since the cave times, when we huddled together in fear for
> safety and for warmth, are happening. Now,” she told them, “now is the
> time to be afraid of the dark.” Richard knew that something was about
> to creep over his face. **He closed his eyes: it made no difference to
> what he saw or felt. The night was complete. It was then that the
> hallucinations started.**

Since it's unlikely that Hunter is bragging, it would appear that the noises that Richard heard (and ascribed to the Beast) were in fact various nasties that would have killed him, had he not been defended.

> He was deep in the sewers, lost in a labyrinth. The Beast was waiting for him. He could hear a slow drip of water. He knew the Beast was waiting. He gripped his spear . . . Then a rumbling bellow, deep in its throat, from behind him. He turned.   Slowly, agonizingly slowly, it charged at him, through the dark.
> And it charged.
> He died.
> And kept walking.
> **Slowly, agonizingly slowly, it charged at him, over and over, through the dark.**

Other than that, we don't really know what happened on the Bridge of Night. Suffice to say it wasn't pleasant.

Comment: Yes Hunter doesn't need to inflate her own ego. I read those too literally as nightmares. It does make sense that real dangers were encountered which was the best reason to sacrifice Anaesthesia, now that you describe it, Richard may have narrowly escaped but only by a hand's width!

Comment: @杜興怡 - Sometimes you just can't save everyone. I don't think that implies that Hunter sacrificed Anaesthesia or valued her less, just that she didn't make it.